# How do I write this query correctly using Amazon redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to write an update query to update the count of a column in the table but I do not know how do I achieve it. I have narrowed it down to three options but I keep on running in some or other problem. Which would be the correct way and correct query for it?

```
update fact_spv_commissioned_lot
set sn_count = fact_spv_commissioned_lot.sn_count + 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM staging_serials s
  JOIN dim_md_company c ON (c.lsc_company_id = s.companyid)
  JOIN staging_product p ON (s.compositeproductcode = p.compositeproductcode)
  JOIN dim_packaging_level l ON (l.unit_of_measure = p.packaginguom)
  JOIN fact_spv_commissioned_lot f ON (f.sk_company_id = s.companyid)
  WHERE c.sk_company_id = f.sk_company_id
  AND s.lotnumber = f.lot_number
  AND p.sk_product_id = f.sk_product_id
  AND l.sk_packaging_level_id = f.sk_packaging_level_id
)
```

or this is the correct way to write it?

```
update fact_spv_commissioned_lot
set sn_count = fact_spv_commissioned_lot.sn_count + 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM staging_serials s
  JOIN dim_md_company c ON (c.lsc_company_id = s.companyid)
  JOIN staging_product p ON (s.compositeproductcode = p.compositeproductcode)
  JOIN dim_packaging_level l ON (l.unit_of_measure = p.packaginguom)
  JOIN fact_spv_commissioned_lot f ON (f.sk_company_id = s.companyid)
  WHERE c.sk_company_id = f.sk_company_id
  AND s.lotnumber = f.lot_number
  AND p.sk_product_id = f.sk_product_id
  AND l.sk_packaging_level_id = f.sk_packaging_level_id
)
FROM staging_serials s
  JOIN dim_md_company c ON (c.lsc_company_id = s.companyid)
  JOIN staging_product p ON (s.compositeproductcode = p.compositeproductcode)
  JOIN dim_packaging_level l ON (l.unit_of_measure = p.packaginguom)
  JOIN fact_spv_commissioned_lot f ON (f.sk_company_id = s.companyid)
  WHERE c.sk_company_id = f.sk_company_id
  AND s.lotnumber = f.lot_number
  AND p.sk_product_id = f.sk_product_id
  AND l.sk_packaging_level_id = f.sk_packaging_level_id
```

or this is the correct way to write it?

```
update fact_spv_commissioned_lot
set sn_count = fact_spv_commissioned_lot.sn_count + 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM staging_serials s
  JOIN dim_md_company c ON (c.lsc_company_id = s.companyid)
  JOIN staging_product p ON (s.compositeproductcode = p.compositeproductcode)
  JOIN dim_packaging_level l ON (l.unit_of_measure = p.packaginguom)
  JOIN fact_spv_commissioned_lot f ON (f.sk_company_id = s.companyid)
)
  WHERE c.sk_company_id = f.sk_company_id
  AND s.lotnumber = f.lot_number
  AND p.sk_product_id = f.sk_product_id
  AND l.sk_packaging_level_id = f.sk_packaging_level_id
```

Comment: What is the primary key of table `fact_spv_commissioned_lot`?

Comment: The downvote might have been because the question is asking an opinion about which is the correct way to write the code, and opinion questions are considered off topic?

Comment: @Ancoron - There is no primary key for the table ```fact_spv_commissioned_lot```. Also this query is to be run with Amazon Redshift.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like [CTE's](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) but your first query is almost there.

A CTE version would be as follows (please replace the `<pk-col>` with the actual primary key column):

```sql
WITH
    agg_data (pk, count) AS (
        SELECT f.<pk-col>, COUNT(*)
        FROM staging_serials s
            JOIN dim_md_company c ON (c.lsc_company_id = s.companyid)
            JOIN staging_product p ON (s.compositeproductcode = p.compositeproductcode)
            JOIN dim_packaging_level l ON (l.unit_of_measure = p.packaginguom)
            JOIN fact_spv_commissioned_lot f ON (f.sk_company_id = s.companyid)
        WHERE c.sk_company_id = f.sk_company_id
            AND s.lotnumber = f.lot_number
            AND p.sk_product_id = f.sk_product_id
            AND l.sk_packaging_level_id = f.sk_packaging_level_id
        GROUP BY 1
    )
UPDATE fact_spv_commissioned_lot AS to_update
SET sn_count = sn_count + agg_data.count
FROM agg_data WHERE agg_data.pk = to_update.<pk-col>;
```

As an alternative, you can also use the original join columns from your sub-select related to the table `fact_spv_commissioned_lot` to make up the correlation with the `JOIN` (`f`) removed, e.g.:

```sql
WITH
    agg_data (sk_company_id, lot_number, sk_product_id, sk_packaging_level_id, count) AS (
        SELECT f.sk_company_id, f.lot_number, f.sk_product_id, f.sk_packaging_level_id, COUNT(*)
        FROM staging_serials s
            JOIN dim_md_company c ON (c.lsc_company_id = s.companyid)
            JOIN staging_product p ON (s.compositeproductcode = p.compositeproductcode)
            JOIN dim_packaging_level l ON (l.unit_of_measure = p.packaginguom)
            JOIN fact_spv_commissioned_lot f ON (f.sk_company_id = s.companyid)
        WHERE c.sk_company_id = f.sk_company_id
            AND s.lotnumber = f.lot_number
            AND p.sk_product_id = f.sk_product_id
            AND l.sk_packaging_level_id = f.sk_packaging_level_id
        GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
    )
UPDATE fact_spv_commissioned_lot AS to_update
SET sn_count = sn_count + agg_data.count
FROM agg_data
WHERE agg_data.sk_company_id = to_update.sk_company_id
    AND agg_data.lot_number = to_update.lot_number
    AND agg_data.sk_product_id = to_update.sk_product_id
    AND agg_data.sk_packaging_level_id = to_update.sk_packaging_level_id
;
```

...or a bit shorter completely with sub-select style:

```sql
UPDATE fact_spv_commissioned_lot AS to_update
SET sn_count = sn_count + (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM staging_serials s
        JOIN dim_md_company c ON (c.lsc_company_id = s.companyid)
        JOIN staging_product p ON (s.compositeproductcode = p.compositeproductcode)
        JOIN dim_packaging_level l ON (l.unit_of_measure = p.packaginguom)
    WHERE s.companyid = to_update.sk_company_id
        AND s.lotnumber = to_update.lot_number
        AND c.sk_company_id = to_update.sk_company_id
        AND p.sk_product_id = to_update.sk_product_id
        AND l.sk_packaging_level_id = to_update.sk_packaging_level_id
);
```

If your tables are medium to large (millions to billions of rows), the CTE-version should also perform magnitudes better (especially the first variant using the primary-key column), although a bit more verbose in SQL.

Comment: When running the last query I am getting this error ```[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "AS" ```

Comment: Ah yes, [Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UPDATE.html) doesn't support this kind of syntax. In that case, just drop the alias. It might also have trouble with the inner/outer reference from the sub-select, but I can't test that. It should support the `WITH` clause queries, though.